# Angular 2 select not change ngModel

Tags: java, angular

There are two select, the second depends on the first:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 control-label">Тип ТС:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10">
            <select class="form-control " type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.TransportTypeId">
                <option *ngFor='let type of transportTypes' [ngValue]='type.Id' [textContent]='type.Name'></option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 control-label">Подтип ТС:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10">
            <select class="form-control " type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.TransportSubTypeId" (ngModelChange)="show()">
                <option [ngValue]="undefined">Не указано</option>
                <option *ngFor="let subType of transportSubTypes | filterBy: ['TransportTypeId']: item.TransportTypeId" [ngValue]='subType.Id' [textContent]='subType.Name'></option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It is assumed that the second `select` can be empty (undefined). At the initial time all works fine, both `select` have values, when the second `ngModelChange` changes, it works. But if I select any value in the first `select`, when the filter for the second `select` returns an empty array, then visually the second `select` is dropped to the value `Not chosen` (`undefined`), but the `ngModel` does not equal `undefined`.

For example:

```
item.TransportTypeId = 1;
item.TransportSubTypeId = 1;
```

change to:

```
item.TransportTypeId = 2;
```

The `filterBy` filter returns [], `item.TransportSubType === 1`, but the value `Not chosen` is selected and the ngModelChange event does not occur.

Help me figure out how to make it so that select automatically resets the value of the model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add component logic as well to understand the query in right direction. But by looking to your query change the code as per below

```
(ngModelChange)="show($event)" 
//component
show(event) { this.val = event.value; }
```

Comment: In ``(ngModelChange)="show()" `` i'm only show current value of item.TransportSubTypeId ``show($event) {
        console.log(this.item.TransportSubTypeId)
        console.log($event);
    }``

Comment: Which module are you using for filterBy?